# XSD desigener error Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xsd

I get the following error if I try to open a .xsd file or create a new one in Visual Studio 2017 its a .net 3.5 project and was working fine before I reinstalled windows and upgraded to visual studio 2017 pro.

This seems to be .net 3.5 specific as I opened another project that's 4.0 and its .xsd opened in designer fine.

> To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the
>   following errors must be resolved:
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter
>   name: instance
>
> ```
>  Instances of this error (1)
> ```
>
> 1. Hide Call Stack    at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(Object instance,
>      Attribute[] attributes) at
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.CreateDesigner(IComponent
>      component, Boolean rootDesigner) at
>      System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.AddToContainerPostProcess(IComponent
>      component, String name, IContainer containerToAddTo) at
>      System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent
>      component, String name) at
>      System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.Add(IComponent component,
>      String name) at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent
>      component) at
>      Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.Designer.DataSourceDesignerLoader.HandleLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>      serializationManager) at
>      Microsoft.VSDesigner.DesignerFramework.BaseDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>      serializationManager) at
>      Microsoft.VSDesigner.DesignerFramework.BaseDesignerLoader.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32
>      fReload)

[Link to error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuTm5.jpg)

Comment: There's no need to post an image of the error. Copy/paste it as text into your post here.

Comment: Yeah done. I was trying to embed the image but it only let me link.

Comment: An image should only be used when the problem can't be presented in any other way, and there was no need whatsoever to include an image here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of reasons to avoid images when possible; it refers to images of code, but many of the bullet items apply to non-code content as well.

Comment: I actually thought it was useful here. I totally agree if you are showing code or an error in a familiar context eg the ones .net gives you in the browser. But I have never seen an error displayed in Visual Studio like this before so I'm trying to show the context as well as the content.

Answer (score 9):

I'm observing the same symptoms you describe and, [as suggested by Tibi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43180799/503410), also found that **changing the Target Framework to 4.6** (via *Website→Start Options→Build* for ASP.NET projects) worked for projects where that was feasible.

I found two open issues for this behavior on the Visual Studio Developer Community website:

- [#26937 - DataSet fails to open in designer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26937/dataset-fails-to-open-in-designer.html)
- [#54432 - Opening Dataset xsd's Throws Designer Error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/54432/opening-dataset-xsds-throws-designer-error.html)

Neither has a solution (other than the Target Framework 4.6 workaround) nor official feedback after more than 6 months.

Answer (score 5):

Hy!
Set your project Target Framework: 4.6
(Right Click the ProjectName/Property Pages/Build/Target Framework--->4.6)
I try it, and it's work.

Comment: Thanks I did end up using the .net version migration extension in VS to change the version to 4.5. I was trying to avoid the version change because of some other outdated stuff being used in the project but it went a lot smoother than I had anticipated.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

My project was targeted to Framework 4.6.1.

And to solve it, I changed the target Framework to 4.7.2.

After that I was then able to open all datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Because some people still get this error maybe this may help you.

1. Open the Project (or Website) Property Page (right click on project > Property Pages > Build.
2. Locate the section where you can choose the .NET Framework version.
3. If your project is using a .NET
   Framework lower than 4.7.2, set it to 4.7.2 (change and restart Visual
   Studio afterwards).
4. If your project is using the .NET Framework
   4.7.2, downgrade it to 4.6.1 (change and restart Visual Studio).

note: link for .NET 4.7.2 ([here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472)), and for .NET 4.6.1 ([here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net461))

Comment: VS2019, project was on 4.6, changed to 4.7.2 than xsd opened without error.

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to a "security" feature that happens when you created the XSD in an older version of Visual Studio and have SQL credentials in the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

This post is old but the problem still exists in 2019. So I post my obstervation:

It seems that the problem comes from the fact that on the applications after 2017 (MVC and Webform) the files of DataSet cannot be placed in the directory App_Code.

You can check and move the files to another folder and you will see that the designer can open them without any problem.

The only problem is that by convention on old projects, the code files must be in App_Code, otherwise compile errors will appear.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem in vs.2019
when i changed .net to 4.7.2 it's ok!

Answer (score 0):

Change the target to 4.7.2 and i used the toolbox for dataset in my case

Answer (score 0):

This problem hit me when changed target framework to 4.8. I was able to overcome it by removing all connections from data adapters in XSD (I don't need them, but probably adding new connections will be ok).

Thanks James Laycock for hint about old connection strings.